# cross-compile c++-File: File format not recognized

Tags: arm, g++, protocol-buffers, onnx

I try to crosscompile a c++-code for an arm-processor from a linux-ubuntu-vm.

A normal compilation works without errors. When I try the following command I've got an error:

**arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ main.cpp onnx.proto3.pb.cc -o readonnx `pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf`**

-->  /**usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

How can I compile my code for an Intel Cyclone V (Linux Angstrom)?

**file /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so**

--> **/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so: symbolic link to libprotobuf.so.20.0.0**

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the problem. You have to compile the protobuf-compiler for arm.

sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lib_arm --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++

Now it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: your solution solved also my problem to cross compile sqlite3. I had the same error in Eclipse: file format not recognized

Answer (score 0):

You need to cross-compile the `libprotobuf.so` library file also.

Currently you are trying to link against the `libprotobuf.so` that is installed on your host system, which is presumably x86 version and thus unknown for ARM compiler.

Comment: How can I cross-compile this library?